# Игнорирование кода специфичного для платформы во время выполнения

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

Есть два приложения на .net framework и .net core, которые вызывают метод из .net standard он в свою очередь еще цепочку методов из других dll .net standard.
Проблема в том, что, в .net standard вызывается метод из System.Runtime.Loader который не поддерживается в .net framework 4.6.1 что и кидает исключение.

Как решить данную проблему?

```
    if (netFramework)
    {
        assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFilePath); // use for .net framework
    }
    else
    {
        // not supported in .net framework
        var context = AssemblyLoadContext.GetLoadContext(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var name = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(assemblyFilePath);
        assembly = context.LoadFromAssemblyName(name); // use for .net core
    }
```

try это не обрабатывает

GetCallingAssembly возвращает не то что нужно 
                [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [#if](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если я правильно понимаю #if срабатывает на этапе компиляции, но не во время выполнения приложения

Comment: @i4el0vek Можно попробовать информацию из `RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription` брать.

Comment: TargetFrameworks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать [RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.frameworkdescription)

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

        string Platform = RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription;
        if (Platform.Contains("Core"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running .NET Core!");
        }
        else if (Platform.Contains("Framework"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running .NET Framework!");
        }
```